# How to remove extra blank above command status-line in vim?

Tags: vim

I managed to get an extra blank link in the bottom-of-the-screen status area in my vim, i.e. in insert mode there is a blank link between the last line of the buffer I'm editing and the command status line where it says "INSERT"", i.e. an *extra* line above the status line. (See screenshot below for illustration.)

It happened like this. I installed the vim-airline plugin. Then, in MacVim, I accidentally dragging the bottom area up by a few lines. I tried to put it back but I could only get it down to 2 lines. I've even uninstalled vim-airline to no avail.

The extra line is there whether in MacVim or vim (via terminal on my OS X system, obviously).

How do I get rid of that extra line and reset the status bar area back to default?

[image: See the blank line between the last ~ and the "INSERT" line? How to get rid of that?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the answer:
`:set cmdheight=1`

(Somehow in all my plugin config it got set to 2 in my .vimrc.)

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of the window, you will *always* have a command-line that is *at least* 1 line high.

Additionally, you may have a statusline (which seems to be the case since you installed a fancyline plugin) that will take up one more line.

Please add a screenshot to your question so we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, I understand there will always be that command-line blank line. I'm talking about an extra blank line ABOVE the command-line, below that last line of the buffer. Added screenshot.

Comment: As for a fancyline plugin -- yes, this came about after I installed vim-airline as noted. But I've uninstalled it and the extra blank line is still there.

Comment: What is the output of `:set laststatus?`?

Comment: I set `laststatus` to zero, no change in behavior. Note that the bottom blank line is where e.g. "-- INSERT --" shows in insert mode, while the blank line above that is where commands show.

Comment: Figured it out: `:set cmdheight=1`